# How to solve y component of this Infinite Solutions question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling with this problem. I've done the work to get infinite (k=-2) and no solutions (k=0), but I'm then told to solve for infinite solutions.

How can you solve for the y component in this problem when y doesn't exist after you sub in the k=-2 values. I'm thinking there should be a t value somewhere but not sure where?

Cheers!

[image]

Comment: $X = (x, y, z) = (2, t, -2)$, that is, infinite solutions. In other words, $y$ can be any value you like since we have the relation $0 \times y = 0$.

Comment: @Amzoti Cheers for that!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
$$ x =2$$
$$ y = s$$
$$ z = -2$$

where $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Here, $y$ is known as a *free variable*.